# How to fix preview Window and fab buttons of camera-preview?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, camera, ionic3

I am using the following code to make a camera-based app. But the preview window is not fixed and easily bud dragging over the screen it replaces. Also `fab buttons` are in behind of preview window. How is possible to fix them over each other on the screen.

**home.ts**

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private cameraPreview: CameraPreview) {
this.startCamera();
  }    
  startCamera() {
    const cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
      x: 40,
      y: 40,
      width: window.screen.width-1,
      height: window.screen.height-1,
      camera: 'rear',
      tapPhoto: true,
      previewDrag: true,
      toBack: false,
      alpha: 1
    };

    this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraPreviewOpts).then(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }

  showCamera(){
    this.cameraPreview.show();
  }

  stopCamera(){
    this.cameraPreview.stopCamera();
  }

  takePicture(){
    const pictureOpts: CameraPreviewPictureOptions = {
      width: 1280,
      height: 1280,
      quality: 85
    }

    this.cameraPreview.takePicture(pictureOpts).then(function(imgData){
      console.log('Picture taken');
      (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('previewPicture')).src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imgData;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

**home.html:**

```
<ion-content padding>

<ion-fab right bottom>
  <button ion-fab color="primary" (click)="takePicture()">
    <ion-icon name="md-camera"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Why are you base64-encoding your image data?  There's no reason to do this.

Comment: @brad, thanks for your comment.  this part of code is just copied. you are right. But my issues are fixing buttons an preview window.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to "send" camera preview to back of the page and disable dragging option.
Try this:

```
const cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
  x: 40,
  y: 40,
  width: window.screen.width-1,
  height: window.screen.height-1,
  camera: 'rear',
  tapPhoto: true,
  previewDrag: false,
  toBack: true,
  alpha: 1
};
```

Your html code seems to be ok so your "fab" button should become visible.
If you want to use preview on whole screen- change `width` & `height` accordingly (remove `-1`) also, 
`x` & `y` determine where your preview vindow will start, so set to `0` if you want to use it on whole screen.
Hope it helps!